# How to access other Vuex modules with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to write a Vuex store with typescript (not using `vuex-module-decorators`, just plain Vuex + typescript to keep things simple).
My root store has no state, just modules:

```
export interface RootState { }
export const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  strict: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  modules: {
    moduleA,
    moduleB
  }
}
```

moduleA has some state:

```
export interface ModAState { 
 aValue: string
}
const modAState: ModAState = {
 aValue: 'value A'
}
export default const moduleA = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: modAState,
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
}
```

as does moduleB:

```
export interface ModBState { 
 bValue: string
}
const modBState: ModBState = {
 bValue: 'value B'
}
const modBActions: ActionTree<ModBState, RootState> = {
  act1({state, rootState, commit, dispatch}) {
    let foo = rootState.moduleA.aValue // <<<<< Typescript error: property moduleA does not exist on '{}' 
  }
}
export default const moduleB = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: modBState,
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: modBActions
}
```

The error is above in modB's `act1` -- `rootState` is just `{}`, as far as typescript is concerned it has no access to the root store's `modules`. So how can I get moduleA's state in an action in moduleB?

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuex-typescript-modules-x7f7s (the store is in `App.vue` there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to typescript your rootState is an empty object

```
// define the interface

/**
 * 
 */
export interface RootState {
  ModAState: ModAState;
  ModBState : ModBState ;
}
```

about the action (without changes)

```
const modBActions: ActionTree<ModBState, RootState> = {
// ...
```

about the action (functions)

```
const modBActions = {
  act1({state, rootState, commit, dispatch}: ActionContext<ModBState, RootState>): Promise<any> {
    let foo = rootState.moduleA.aValue 
  },
}

// ...
```

If your rootState is undergoing many changes, you can skip this for a moment (not recommended)

```
const modBActions: ActionTree<ModBState, any> = {
// ...
```

Comment: so there's no (typesafe) access from the root store to its modules? Too bad. But this is a good workaround; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For type safety with `Vuex` you could use [direct-vuex](https://github.com/paleo/direct-vuex). That way you can access modules [directly](https://github.com/paleo/direct-vuex#use-typed-wrappers-from-outside-the-store) from the store.

Comment: Is it possible to define the store using `vuex-module-decorators` and make it types using `direct-vuex`?

Comment: i'm trying to use this solution but having lot of problems with undefined values in module states so I guess it is not possible